# Are Field History tracking objects the only Salesforce objects that have fields of DisplayType "ANYTYPE"?

Tags: metadata, standard-objects, schema

Field History tracking objects, such as "AccountHistory", "ContactHistory", etc., keep track of changes to field values on records of objects with History tracking enabled on those fields. The original and updated values are stored in the "OldValue" and "NewValue" fields, respectively, both of which have a `Schema.DisplayType` of `ANYTYPE` (see [the list of possible Schema.DisplayType Enum values](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm)).

My question is, are Field History tracking objects the ONLY place in Salesforce that you'll encounter fields of DisplayType "ANYTYPE", or are there other places as well?

Comment: That's a peculiar question, wonder why you need that info :) No idea to be honest but I'd check "mutant lookups" (like Activities can be linked to many objects) and maybe `Task.Subject` that's a freetext but you can select from "picklist".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I found my answer --- according to the docs on Salesforce [Primitive Data Types](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_primitives.htm):

> AnyType is used within the Force.com platform database exclusively for sObject fields in field history tracking tables.

Comment: Looks like an answer to me :) this is certainly a dark corner of the platform you have shed some light on